# Calling Subclass Method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Given the following situation (UML below),

If Y has the method:

```
public void PrintWs();
```

and X has:

```
ArrayList <P> myPs = new ArrayList();

Y y = new Y();
Z z = new Z();
myPs.add(y);
myPs.add(z);
```

How do I loop through each myPs object and call all Ys PrintWs (without using instanceof)?

http://starbucks.mirror.waffleimages.com/files/68/68c26b815e913acd00307bf27bde534c0f1f8bfb.jpg

Sorry, to clarify:

- Z contains 1 Y object.
- Y and Z are both subclasses of P
- The image seems to work if you refresh - My reputation is too low to upload images, so I will edit when I acquire 15 points :)

Comment: How are the classes Y and Z related?

Comment: Are Y and Z both subclasses of P?

Comment: Me too(403) ... do something OR i will die .. plzz

Comment: Why you want to avoid the instanceof? Probably your problem can be solved in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - assuming you only want to *try* to call `PrintWs` on instances of Y, you need to determine which references *are* pointing at instances of Y... and that's where you use `instanceof`. (You could use `Y.class.isInstance(p)` but that's just the same thing in a slightly different form.)

Of course if you can make P contain a no-op `PrintWs` which is then overridden in Y, then you can call it on everything in the list...

Comment: Thanks for the straight-forward answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* try to downcast to `Y` in a try block and catch any `ClassCastException`... this is not something I would do in my code, but literally taken, answers your question :-)

A better solution would be to move up `PrintWs()` (with an empty default implementation) to class `P` - then you can call it on all elements of `myPs` without downcast.

Answer (score 0):

If Y and Z are subclasses of P then you can move the declaration of the method to P with an empty implementation and override it in Y.  This way you can call the method on all objects in your ArrayList but only those that are instances of Y will have an implementation for the method.